# Question regarding RDP Brute force location

Tags: azure

Im looking into where exactly i can find these details ? We have an inbound rule about RDP.
But i recieved this image but fail to find it in the Azure portal ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsQnc.png]

Answer (score 0):

- *To Detect RDP brute force in Azure you need to use Azure Sentinel.*
- *Once you enable Azure Sentinel you can view these events in Azure log analytics workspace.*
  [image]
- *You need to install Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA) in all the VM you want to check the brute force.*

[image: > Blockquote]

- *In log analytics workspace you need to configure Agent configuration.*

[image]

- *After enabling Log Analytics Workspace, you need to create a Schedule query rule in Azure sentinel dashboard.*

[image]

- *Here is the KQL script for log analytics workspace*

```sql
SecurityEvent
| where EventID == 4625
| project TimeGenerated, EventID, WorkstationName, Computer, Account, LogonTypeName, IpAddress
| extend AccountEntity = Account
| extend IPEntity = IpAddress
```

- *Go through this Azure sentinel [document](https://charbelnemnom.com/detect-a-brute-force-attack-with-azure-sentinel/) for complete information.*